# The number of non isomorphic homogenous models of T

Tags: logic, model-theory

> D. Marker, Model Theory:
>   Corollary 4.3.24. The number of non isomorphic homogeneous models of $T$ of size $\kappa$ is at most $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.
>   Proof.
>   **Homogeneous models of cardinality $\kappa$ are determined by the set of types realized**. Because $|S_n(T)| ≤ 2^{\aleph_0}$, the number of possible sets of types realized in a model is at most $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

I can't understand why the sentence which I've made it bold in the proof is true. Would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Theorem 4.3.23, which appears directly before Corollary 4.3.24.

Marker probably should have written "Homogeneous models of cardinality $\kappa$ are determined *up to isomorphism* by the set of types realized."

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's true to be written "up to isomorphism".